# bootstrap html web page layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap framework to make responsive web page to worl on mobile , PC and tablet.
I wrote the fallowing code and I was run it on browser but the result not good when the browser size going as same as mobile screen.

see the following html code and run it and change the browser size to see the result.

see the result on A,B,C,D blocks

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

<style>
.but
{
background-color: red;
font-size:40px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
border-width:1px;
border-left: 1px solid red;
border-right: 1px solid red;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#DBE8D7;">
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red; border-top-right-radius:8px; border-top-left-radius:8px; background-color:white;font-size:75px;margin-bottom:0px;border-bottom:none;">div1</div>
<br/>
<a href='#' class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 but">A</a>
<a href='#' class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 but">B</a>
<a href='#' class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 but">C</a>
<a href='#' class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 but">D</a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Look at the the set of `col-xs` classes. They're a mobile first version of columns.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly put col-xs as it will be inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use *col-xx-zz* classes on `<a>` tags. Also if you want to have the same setup of columns on mobile device as on PC monitor one declaration: col-xs-3 is enough, no need to use sm, md, lg etc...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

<style>
.but
{
background-color: red;
font-size:40px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
border-width:1px;
border-left: 1px solid red;
border-right: 1px solid red;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#DBE8D7;">
<div class="container">


<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red; border-top-right-radius:8px; border-top-left-radius:8px; background-color:white;font-size:75px;margin-bottom:0px;border-bottom:none;">div1</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"><a href='#' class="but">A</a></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><a href='#' class="but">B</a></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><a href='#' class="but">C</a></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><a href='#' class="but">D</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't perfect, but something like this might work:

Change the `font-size` attribute to `15vw`:

```
font-size: 15vw;
```

and in your HTML, no need to use col-lg-3, col-md-3, col-sm-3 if you plan to use the same orientation all the way down to col-xs-3. To get a better idea about how this column system works, take a look at the documentation for the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```
<a href='#' class="col-xs-3 but">A</a>
<a href='#' class="col-xs-3 but">B</a>
<a href='#' class="col-xs-3 but">C</a>
<a href='#' class="col-xs-3 but">D</a>
```

Ideally this isn't the best way to go about it. The better way would be to have the menu turn into a drop-down menu for smaller screens. Bootstrap provides functionality for that.

For that, take a look at the documentation for the [navigation bar.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)